# Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings after visiting PHPmyAdmin and FTP

Tags: wordpress

So, I was going to start building a new Wordpress based website. On the same URL there was an old website where I must get all of the content and details etc.

Just to make sure that I had all of the right logins from site owner I logged into phpMyAdmin and FTP - did not modify or change anything!

And now I cannot access the site from it's URL, instead I get this error:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: core/Loader.php  
Line Number: 346
```

And when I go to core/Loader.php on line 346 there is:

```
$CI->db =& DB($params, $active_record);
```

Could anyone guess what could have possibly gone wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try the below,

Goto: `application->config->database.php`

And make sure you have setup the **correct details**.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; //set your host name
$db['default']['username'] = ''; //databse username
$db['default']['password'] = ''; //databse password
$db['default']['database'] = ''; //database name
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; //database driver
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;$active_group = 'default';
```

Also i suggest you to auto load the **database** library as below,

Goto: `application->config->autoload.php`

And then `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`